# XCUIElement hierarchy within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, uiaccessibility

I encountered a strange behaviour in UI-tests.
When I add a custom view into UITableViewCell, some of it's subviews are not accessible.
However, it's OK in Xcode's Debug View Hierarchy.

Yes, I know about UIAccessibilityContainer but it's not a solution cause of:
1. there are regular subviews in my custom view (views, labels, images), not a drawn content.
2. I can't disable isAccessibilityElement for containerView and enable it for ImageView cause of I need both in the same time.

So, when I add my view to TableViewCell as-is, I can access only few elements from UI-tests:

```
Table, 0x604000196da0, traits: 35192962023424, {{5.0, 108.0}, {404.0, 586.0}}
  Cell, 0x604000384b90, traits: 8589934592, {{5.0, 132.0}, {365.0, 329.0}}
    StaticText, 0x6040003849f0, traits: 8589934656, {{9.0, 135.7}, {25.0, 12.7}}, identifier: 'myLabel', label: '123'
    StaticText, 0x604000384780, traits: 8589934656, {{73.0, 154.3}, {293.0, 18.7}}, identifier: 'titleLabel', label: 'Title'
```

If I enable isAccessibilityElement for images, I can see it as well:

```
Table, 0x604000196da0, traits: 35192962023424, {{5.0, 108.0}, {404.0, 586.0}}
  Cell, 0x604000384b90, traits: 8589934592, {{5.0, 132.0}, {365.0, 329.0}}
    Image, 0x604000384ac0, traits: 8589934596, {{9.0, 235.7}, {357.0, 174.3}}, identifier: 'myImage'
    StaticText, 0x6040003849f0, traits: 8589934656, {{9.0, 135.7}, {25.0, 12.7}}, identifier: 'myLabel', label: '123'
    StaticText, 0x604000384780, traits: 8589934656, {{73.0, 154.3}, {293.0, 18.7}}, identifier: 'titleLabel', label: 'Title'
    Image, 0x604000384370, traits: 8589934596, {{9.0, 156.3}, {56.0, 56.0}}, identifier: 'myIcon'
```

But, in both cases a hierarchy within Cell is plain and there are no container views.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is: use UICollectionView instead of UITableView.**

Here is a correct hierarchy (isAccessibilityElement has default value for each element).

```
Other, 0x600000193590, traits: 8589934592, {{5.0, 132.0}, {365.0, 604.0}}
  CollectionView, 0x6000001930b0, traits: 35192962023424, {{5.0, 132.0}, {365.0, 573.0}}
    Cell, 0x600000192fe0, traits: 8589934592, {{5.0, 132.0}, {365.0, 329.0}}
      Other, 0x600000192f10, traits: 8589934592, {{5.0, 132.0}, {365.0, 329.0}}
        Other, 0x6040001900c0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 129.7}, {375.0, 333.7}}, identifier: 'myView'
          Other, 0x604000192e40, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 129.7}, {375.0, 333.9}}, identifier: 'contentView'
            StaticText, 0x60400018f970, traits: 8589934656, {{4.0, 133.7}, {25.0, 12.7}}, identifier: 'myLabel', label: '123'
            Image, 0x60400018fd80, traits: 8589934596, {{4.0, 154.3}, {56.0, 56.0}}, identifier: 'myIcon'
            StaticText, 0x60400018f7d0, traits: 8589934656, {{68.0, 152.3}, {303.0, 18.7}}, identifier: 'titleLabel', label: 'Title'
            Other, 0x60400018ee10, traits: 8589934592, {{4.0, 233.7}, {367.0, 179.2}}, identifier: 'containerView'
              Image, 0x60400018eba0, traits: 8589934596, {{4.0, 233.7}, {367.0, 179.2}}, identifier: 'myImage'
```