# Why is XCTest exposing a random otherElement in a UITableViewCell? (and exhibiting other inconsistencies)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xctest, xcuitest

I created a new single view project and added this code to create a UITableView.

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10,30,320,400);
    tableView.dataSource=self;
    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
    cell.textLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = @"world";
    return cell;
}
```

My UI test simply prints the view hierarchy with `print(app.debugDescription)` and as you can see the graph for the main window has 2 leaf views: a `StaticText` corresponding to `cell.textLabel` and an unidentified/random `Other` view.  I've tried many ways to figure out what this `Other` view is but the answer eludes me.

```
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x600000d98820, pid: 17292, label: 'TestApp'
    Window (Main), 0x600000d989c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
      Other, 0x600000d98a90, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
        Table, 0x600000d98b60, {{10.0, 30.0}, {320.0, 400.0}}
          Cell, 0x600000d98c30, {{10.0, 30.0}, {320.0, 44.0}}
            StaticText, 0x600000d98d00, {{25.0, 30.0}, {290.0, 43.5}}, identifier: 'world', label: 'hello'
            Other, 0x600000d98dd0, {{25.0, 73.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}
```

Perhaps it is more of [this UITableViewCell odd/unexplained behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981332/xcuielement-hierarchy-within-uitableviewcell)?

The other strangeness that leads me to this is when a `UIScrollView` containing a `UILabel` is added to a `UITableViewCell`, the `UIScrollView` does not appear in the hierarchy.  So this:

```c
- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    UILabel *lb = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 5,5)];
    [lb setText:@"hello world"];
    [sv addSubview:lb];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:sv];
    return cell;
}
```

yields this:

```
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x6000014e75a0, pid: 20372, label: 'TestApp'
    Window (Main), 0x6000014e7190, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
      Other, 0x6000014e6ff0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
        Table, 0x6000014e6f20, {{10.0, 30.0}, {320.0, 400.0}}
          Cell, 0x6000014e6e50, {{10.0, 30.0}, {320.0, 44.0}}
            StaticText, 0x6000014e6d80, {{10.0, 30.0}, {5.0, 5.0}}, label: 'hello world'
            Other, 0x6000014e6cb0, {{25.0, 73.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}
```

Whereas this (no table or cell involved):

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    UILabel *lb = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 5,5)];
    [lb setText:@"hello world"];
    [sv addSubview:lb];
    [self.view addSubview:sv];
}
```

seems to work just fine:

```
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x600000278750, pid: 20442, label: 'TestApp'
    Window (Main), 0x6000002788f0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
      Other, 0x600000278820, {{0.0, 0.0}, {768.0, 1024.0}}
        ScrollView, 0x6000002789c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {10.0, 10.0}}
          StaticText, 0x600000278a90, {{0.0, 0.0}, {5.0, 5.0}}, label: 'hello world'
```

My thoughts are that this is all somehow related to the way `isAccessibilityElement`, `accessibilityTraits` and whether or not a view is a container determine what gets exposed but the inconsistency is bewildering and I'm hoping someone else knows the secret formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other element is the separation line between cells. 
Since these lines don't affect other elements, they should not bother you.

When you make some element accessible, its descendants don't appear in UI tests elements tree.

Comment: So I'm satisfied for the first half of my question, but I'd like to better understand the hows and whys of "When you make some element accessible, its descendants don't appear in UI tests elements tree"

Comment: Let's take a single tabbar button for example.

It is a view with two subviews – an image and a text. 

You definitely don't want to make these subviews accessible since making tabbar button accessible is just enough for VoiceOver users. 

iOS automatically hides the subviews of accessible element – and that is the behaviour you need in 99% cases. 

If you want your elements to be accessed differently when VoiceOver enabled and when UI tests are run, you should support it on your own. Probably with some environment variable.